# Error on doInBackground() android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I am trying to do a http request/response from a android activity ( a simple login form) but after i finished the code it gives me an error , because i have to put it in a thread , im not familiar with async task but i have tried to implement it but ,now when i run the program and hit submit it logcat gives me something like

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
Process: com.example.httpgetandroidexample, PID: 1131
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:300)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.checkThread(ViewRootImpl.java:6094)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.requestLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:824)
at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16431)
at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16431)
at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16431)
at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16431)
at android.widget.RelativeLayout.requestLayout(RelativeLayout.java:352)
at android.view.View.requestLayout(View.java:16431)
at android.widget.TextView.checkForRelayout(TextView.java:6600)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3813)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3671)
at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3646)
at com.example.httpgetandroidexample.MainActivity$AsyncTaskRunner.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:87)
at com.example.httpgetandroidexample.MainActivity$AsyncTaskRunner.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
... 4 more
```

and i cant understand why! here it is my android activity :

```
package com.example.httpgetandroidexample;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    public TextView content;
    EditText name,pass;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
        pass = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass);
        content = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);

        Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.but);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                AsyncTaskRunner runner = new AsyncTaskRunner();
                runner.execute();
            }
        });


    }
    class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        private String resp;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            publishProgress("Working..."); // Calls onProgressUpdate()
            try{ 

                // URLEncode user defined data

                String nameValue    = URLEncoder.encode(name.getText().toString(), "UTF-8");
                String passValue    = URLEncoder.encode(pass.getText().toString(), "UTF-8");

                // Create http cliient object to send request to server

                HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();

                // Create URL string

                String URL = "http://localhost:8080/login/web?user="+nameValue+"&pass="+passValue;

                //Log.i("httpget", URL);

                try
                {
                    String SetServerString = "";

                    // Create Request to server and get response

                    HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(URL);
                    ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                    SetServerString = Client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);

                    // Show response on activity 

                    content.setText(SetServerString);
                }
                catch(Exception ex)
                {
                    content.setText("fail");
                    System.out.println(ex);
                    resp="fail";
                }
            }
            catch(UnsupportedEncodingException ex)
            {
                content.setText("FailAndroid!");
                resp="fail";
            } 
            return resp;
        }
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            content.setText(result);
        }
        protected void onPreExecute() {
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(String... text) {
            content.setText(text[0]);

        }
    }
}
```

my code it shows no error , not even a warning but when i push the submit button it force closes after the "working" message appears ,does anyone has any idea why?
Thank you in advance

With all your help (thank you all!) i have modified my activity code like this :

```
package com.example.httpgetandroidexample;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

               public TextView content;
                EditText name,pass;

            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                     name      =  (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
                     pass       =  (EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass);
                     content       =  (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);

                   Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.but);

                   button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onClick(View v) {
                        AsyncTaskRunner runner = new AsyncTaskRunner();
                        runner.execute();
                       }
                      });


   }
            class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

              private String resp;

              @Override
              protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
               publishProgress("Working..."); // Calls onProgressUpdate()
              try{ 

                                     // URLEncode user defined data

                                       String nameValue    = URLEncoder.encode(name.getText().toString(), "UTF-8");
                                       String passValue    = URLEncoder.encode(pass.getText().toString(), "UTF-8");

                                    // Create http cliient object to send request to server

                                       HttpClient Client = new DefaultHttpClient();

                                    // Create URL string

                                     String URL = "http://localhost:8080/login/web?user="+nameValue+"&pass="+passValue;

                                    //Log.i("httpget", URL);

                                   try
                                    {
                                                  String SetServerString = "";

                                                // Create Request to server and get response

                                                  HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet(URL);
                                                 ResponseHandler<String> responseHandler = new BasicResponseHandler();
                                                 SetServerString = Client.execute(httpget, responseHandler);

                                                  // Show response on activity 

                                                return SetServerString;
                                     }
                                   catch(Exception ex)
                                      {
                                     Log.i("MyActivity","Exception");
                                       }
                                }
                              catch(UnsupportedEncodingException ex)
                               {

                                   Log.i("MyActivity","UnsupportedEncodingException");
                                } 
              return resp;
                            }
              @Override
              protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
               content.setText(result);
              }
              protected void onPreExecute() {
              }

              @Override
              protected void onProgressUpdate(String... text) {
               content.setText(text[0]);

              }
             }
}
```

but now i get the  `Log.i("MyActivity","Exception");` message i put on it , im still doing something wrong ?

**UPDATE**

And for my last try i modified the code yet again following some tutorials online and this is what i have done

```
package com.example.httpgetandroidexample;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.ResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicResponseHandler;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

               public TextView content;
                EditText name,pass;
                String URL;
            @Override
            protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

                      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                     setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

                     name      =  (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
                     pass       =  (EditText)findViewById(R.id.pass);
                     content       =  (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);

                   Button button=(Button)findViewById(R.id.but);
                   try {
                    String nameValue    = URLEncoder.encode(name.getText().toString(), "UTF-8");
                       String passValue    = URLEncoder.encode(pass.getText().toString(), "UTF-8");
                       URL = "http://localhost:8080/login/web?user="+nameValue+"&pass="+passValue;
                } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                   button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                       @Override
                       public void onClick(View v) {
                        AsyncTaskRunner runner = new AsyncTaskRunner();
                        runner.execute(new String[ ] { URL });
                       }
                      });


   }
            private class AsyncTaskRunner extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {


                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
                  String response = "";
                  for (String url : urls) {
                    DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                    try {
                      HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
                      InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

                      BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                      String s = "";
                      while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
                        response += s;
                      }

                    } catch (Exception e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                  }
                  return response;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
                  content.setText(result);
                }
              }
}
```

and here it is what the logcat in verbose mode:

```
Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)
at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:418)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:137)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
at com.example.httpgetandroidexample.MainActivity$AsyncTaskRunner.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:69)
at com.example.httpgetandroidexample.MainActivity$AsyncTaskRunner.doInBackground(MainActivity.java:1)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
Caused by: libcore.io.GaiException: getaddrinfo failed: EAI_NODATA (No address associated with hostname)
at libcore.io.Posix.getaddrinfo(Native Method)
at libcore.io.ForwardingOs.getaddrinfo(ForwardingOs.java:61)
at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:405)
... 17 more
Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: getaddrinfo failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
... 20 more
```

from what i cand understand its a missing permission but the problem is that i have it on my  manifest file :

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET">
```

Comment: its a crash. post the full stacktrace

Comment: why u encode UTF-8 to java string it is default UTF-8 dude

Comment: if can debug and post the full log

Comment: delete the `content.setText(SetServerString);` from the method `doInBackground()`. the UI cannot be modified or touched from this method, if you want to update your UI, you can do that on the `onPostExecute()` method. here an example of using asynctask while downloading an image from server : http://www.android-ios-tutorials.com/182/show-progressbar-while-downloading-image-using-asynctask-in-android/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Logcat error:

**Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.**

you try working with UI thread in `doInBackground`,

```
content.setText("fail");
```

you cannot touch anything in the ui thread from a background thread use `onPostExecute` for working with UI

This is one sample of what you want.

```
 private class DownloadWebPageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {
      String response = "";
      for (String url : urls) {
        DefaultHttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
        try {
          HttpResponse execute = client.execute(httpGet);
          InputStream content = execute.getEntity().getContent();

          BufferedReader buffer = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
          String s = "";
          while ((s = buffer.readLine()) != null) {
            response += s;
          }

        } catch (Exception e) {
          e.printStackTrace();
        }
      }
      return response;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
      textView.setText(result);
    }
  }
```

you need return your String from `doInBackground`

In sample: `return response;`

for returning that you need change:

In sample:

1- `AsyncTask<String, Void, String>` <--- last value is what you want get from `doInBackground` more info in [This site](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

2- `protected String doInBackground` <--- change return type to String

3 - return your value  `return response;`

4- `protected void onPostExecute(String result)`  <--- this must be String too

then work with UI in `onPostExecute`

in Sample `onPostExecute(String result)`  <--- result is your String

Copied code from [Vogella Article](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html) `6.5. Example: AsyncTask`

**UPDATE**

you work with UI again on:

```
String nameValue    = URLEncoder.encode(name.getText().toString(), "UTF-8");
String passValue    = URLEncoder.encode(pass.getText().toString(), "UTF-8");
```

if you want this value you can send those to constructor of asynctask or send as parameter to `doInBackground`, i recommend second way

as your code in try catch statement your application not closed, an as you don't print any thing useful on catch you can't get your error, if you use catch it's more proper that print error too like:

```
catch(UnsupportedEncodingException ex)
 {
    ex.printStackTrace();
 }
```

**UPDATE 2**

you declare your android permission as following in your code:

```
android:permission="android.permission.INTERNET">
```

but you must add your permission like:

```
<manifest xlmns:android...>
 ...
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
</manifest>
```

your manifest must be like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest  
    ......
    ......
    .....>

<uses-sdk
    ...... />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<application
     .......
     .......
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply , i have read it once (the article ) but i didnt understand it well , thank to you now i have , but still after i modified the code i get a Exception error i dont know why any idea? also i have to add now the app doesnt force close but still not showing the server reply !

Comment: i have posted the new code but on logcat i dont get any errors only some saing `error loading ............ogg "

Comment: Well i have moved my `nameValue` and `passValue` on the top of the async class and let the `URL` on doInBackground(); also i have modified the log into `Log.i("MyActivity",ex.toString());` and i get a denied internet permission but on my manifest file its everything ok !

Comment: please post logcat and manifest file, try clean your project too

Comment: just this message : `java.lang.SecurityException: Permission denied (missing INTERNET permission?)` also im a little afraid to clean the project as it deletes (or make unusable) my R file!

Comment: ok i have updated the code and the logcat , i know im getting boring but i need to do this and understand well how i can use asynctask to send/recevie httprequest , also this project is very important to me

Comment: see my update again @p3rand0r, and your problem is not related to this post, you can ask new question with your problem instead of ask in comment

Comment: You are right :), thank you sir ,everythin works now thank you again :)

Answer (score 2):

You can not work with the UI in doInBackground ! Everytime your code gets into `content.setText()` in **doInBackground** it will crash.

Answer (score 1):

> Caused by: android.view.ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException:
>   Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its
>   views.

The stacktrace says you are updating ui from a backgroudn thread which is wrong.

You have

```
content.setText(SetServerString);
```

You are updating the same in `doInbackground` which is wrong.

You can update ui only from ui thread. `doInBackground` is invoked on the background thread. `onPostExecute` is invoked on the ui thread. So you ca return in `doInBackgorund` and update ui in `onPostExecute`.

Check the topic **The 4 Steps** @

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Also instead of  `System.out.println(ex);` use `Log` to log the info.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/util/Log.html

Comment: thank you for your reply i didnt know i have to put all the hi threads on onPostExecute , but still i get an error :/

Comment: @p3rand0r background operation in `doInbackground` only ui update in `onPostExecute`. read the link posted in my post again

Comment: well i modified the code again , but still nothing this time i get a internet missing permission , but on my manifest file its everything ok , also didnt know you cant use at all your ui on the doInBackground , just you cant change them , thnx for the reply!

Comment: @p3rand0r you need to add permissionin manifest. You should have patience and read the docs. add this in manifest `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>`

Comment: @p3rand0r that permission must be above application tag in manifest. this is basic stuff and you can read the same in the docs

Answer (score 1):

`content.setText();` in `doInbackground` is making the error..You cant update UI in `doInbackground`..Anything that changes the UI should be moved to `onPostExecute`

Answer (score 1):

All modifications on the User Interface (anything that the user sees like Buttons or TextFields) have to be performed by the main thread (UI Thread). The code in the doInBackground() method runs on a different thread. Hence, you should download data here (which is the time consuming computation) and then change your UI with the queried information in the onPostExecute() method.